# Logic problems with a User PHP Class (OOP)

Tags: php, class, oop, object, methods

Today I come with a logical problem.

I have a class that gives me complete information of the user. I've created a method that allows me to recover all the data of each user how return me an object.

Here is the method :

```
public static function getAllUsers(&$rUsersData = null, $sArgs = null) {

        // Nouvelle connexion à la base de données
        self::$oDatabase = new cMySQLi(DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_HOSTPORT, DB_DATABASE);

        // Si on ne passe pas de ressource en paramètre
        if(is_null($rUsersData)) {

            // Récupère les données de tout les users, actifs ou non
            $sReqSelectAllUsers = ' SELECT
                                        *
                                    FROM
                                        '.self::$sTableName.(is_null($sArgs) ? ' '.$sArgs.' ' : null).'
                                    ORDER BY
                                        '.self::$sFieldFirstname.' ASC';

            // Exécute la requête
            $rUsersData = self::$oDatabase->Query($sReqSelectAllUsers);
        }

        // Associe les données dans un tableau associatif à 2 dimensions
        $aUsersData = self::$oDatabase->Assoc($rUsersData);

        // Parcours chaque utilisateurs
        while($aData = $aUsersData) {

            // Retourne un objet avec les données de l'user
            return new cUser($aData[self::$sFieldId]);
        }

    }
```

And here is the call that I use to recover all data :

```
while($aUser = cUser::getAllUsers()) {

    print_r($aUser);
}
```

Here is my cMySQLi class if it can also help you : https://github.com/SatanicGeek/S.A.V-Team-Manager/blob/master/www/classes/mysqli.class.php

Could you help me to get all the users without any param in the method call (I can get of the users if I pass a sql ressource to my method) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `getAllUsers()` method you have a while loop that returns; this will only return a single user (return exits the loop & function, returning the value to the caller).

Since you want to return an array of all the users, instead use code *similar* to this:

```
$listOfUsers = [];

foreach($aUsersData as $aData) {
  $listOfUsers[] = new cUser($aData);
}
return $listOfUsers;
```

This way when you call the code, you'll have an array of user objects, not just a single user object.

For example to call this method, you would now use code like:

```
$allUsers = cUser::getAllUsers();
foreach($allUsers as $user) {
  print_r($user);
}
```

*Technically this could be solved with using `yield` and making getAllUsers() as a generator but this would have horrible implications around the MySQL connection*

Comment: It's a possibility but that's not what I want. I'm training with PHP. Thank you.